# Deploying C# SQL Server SMO application

Tags: c#, sql, dll, reference, smo

Forgive me if this is not the correct forum for this ask but I have a c# application that uses SMO to setup a database on a remote server.  I am wondering how to deploy this application as it works fine on my dev server but when I deploy it is missing batchparser and batchparser.client.dll files. They exist in the bin folder and I have referenced them by installing the `Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO` nuget package.

According to the official documentation:

> Beginning with SQL Server 2017 SMO is distributed as the Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects NuGet package to allow users to develop applications with SMO.
>
> This is a replacement for SharedManagementObjects.msi, which was previously released as part of the SQL Feature Pack for each release of SQL Server. Applications that use SMO should be updated to use the NuGet package instead and will be responsible for ensuring the binaries are installed with the application being developed.

I would assume this to mean I should be able to install the nuget package and all should be referenced correctly. Am I missing something big here? Does SQL Server need to be installed on the machine I am running my C# application from?

My architecture is as follows:

1. Web server
2. SQL Server

Web admin logs into (1) web server and runs my c# program which sets up some IIS based .net websites on that machine, then from the web server it will REMOTELY setup a database by running the smo commands. The C# program will execute the commands on the web server and remotely configure a SQL Server (2)(another machine).

Can this be achieved using C# and SMO without having an instance of SQL/SQL tools on the web server?

Thanks

Comment: this is my question also.... any response?